# GDI Double Buffer Black Flicker

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+, gdi

I am using this BitBlt wrapper:

> > http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21426/Double-Buffering-in-a-Win-API-Program

I initialize it in main():

```cpp
biop = new Bitmap_Operations();
biop->Initialize_Buffers(m_hDC, m_hWND, 1);
biop->Create_Buffer(0);
```

Helper Functions:

```
void CreateBuffer()
{
    biop->Create_Buffer(0);
}

void Render()
{
    biop->Copy_to_Screen(0);
}

void ClearBuffer()
{
    biop->Free_Buffer(0);
}

void DrawBox(int x, int y, int r, int g, int b, int size, int thickness)
{
    // Brush style to hollow
    m_LogBrush.lbStyle = BS_NULL;

    // Create a logical brush and select into the context
    m_hBrush = CreateBrushIndirect(&m_LogBrush);
    HBRUSH hbrOldBrush = (HBRUSH)SelectObject(biop->Get_DC_Buffer(0), m_hBrush);

    // Create a logical pen and select into the context
    m_hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, thickness, RGB(r, g, b));
    HPEN hpOldPen = (HPEN)SelectObject(biop->Get_DC_Buffer(0), m_hPen);

    // Draw the rectangle
    Rectangle(biop->Get_DC_Buffer(0), (x - size / 2), (y - size / 2), (x + size / 2), (y + size / 2));

    // Remove the object
    SelectObject(biop->Get_DC_Buffer(0), hbrOldBrush);  // first you must restore DC to original state
    SelectObject(biop->Get_DC_Buffer(0), hpOldPen);     // same here
    DeleteObject(m_hBrush);
    DeleteObject(m_hPen);
}
```

I spawn a thread to render data:

```
// Inside a thread
while (1)
{
    CreateBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1028; i++)
    {
        //

        DrawBox()

        //
    }
    Render();
    ClearBuffer();
}
```

I am using FindWindow() to render on top of another application. Everything works fine, the boxes get rendered, ect, but there is a crazy full-screen flicker that seems to have a black background. My guess its when I draw from memory to the application?

I am using double buffering to avoid a flicker, but it seems like it made it worse. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it also flicker if you try drawing on top of your own app-windows? I guess windows might have some problems with you just carelessly drawing over other's windows.

Comment: Manipulating a window from a thread that is not the owner of a window is an unsupported scenario. All expectations are off, and this will not be a robust solution.

Comment: You're the same person that asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755972/prevent-flickering-when-drawing). Why are you using a separate account? Also you never answered my question about how, when, why you're drawing or what you're trying to accomplish. Please answer these questions and stop trying to double buffer without knowing what you're doing first. (It is a shame that some people preferred answering the question rather than solving the problem.)

Comment: Yeah same person, I was using a different computer and was unable to login as the same account, hence the new account. My application loads up, initializes the buffer, uses FindWindow() to get a handle to the window (in my test cases I am using "Untitled - Notepad"), creates a thread with the loop above, and inside that loop draws 64 boxes on the screen using x/y coords that I have transitions moving the coords for each box.

Comment: Without using double buffering, everything works but the rectangles flicker, when using double buffering, the rectangles are now smooth and dont flicker as much, but the entire window flickers black.

Comment: Double buffering solves an entirely different problem than what you're trying to do (namely, it solves flicker in heavy-duty paint operations in your own window, and to a lesser extent painting your own window very quickly to do animation). You're trying to draw over another window, and draw outside the Windows paint model to boot. You'll need to look up how to do what you're actually trying to do: draw on top of a foreign window. Good luck!

Comment: Also, are you trying to animate something, or draw something static/responsive to another event? That will also help.

Comment: Actually I'm wrong; flicker can happen when doing constant erases and redraws too, but that's still not the solution to your problem.

Comment: Yeah from my understanding, the flicker is due to multiple re-draws which remove and re-create the box. For the animations, I am just calling DrawBox() again with new x/y coords. Youre saying double buffering doesnt solve the multiple re-draw problem?

Comment: No, I'm saying your original problem is that you want to draw onto another window outside your own process. Double-buffering is a way to get rid of flicker, yes, but it only works if you are doing everything else correctly: namely, you are drawing in your own window, and only on a `WM_PAINT` message. What you want to do isn't part of that at all. You'll need to find out how to draw onto another window. I have a feeling that this isn't going to be possible, or if so, very difficult/dangerous, but I've never tried. What is your ultimate goal with this project?

Comment: I am basically making it so you can "screen saver" any application you want. Be in notepad, press a command, a bunch of rectangles appear and do some cool animations until a stop event. Would it work if I create a transparent window over everything and use that for drawing/swaping?

Answer (score 0):

I would use UpdateLayeredWindow APIs instead, if you need to draw transparent things on top of existing windows.